# Customize Issue Tracker list form with powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have an issue tracker list in SharePoint 2013 environment. In the course of migration to SharePoint online, we are successfully able to migrate Issue Tracker list. Now the goal is to customize the list form using powerapps. In list setting -> form settings, the option to customize the form is not available. If we plan to create an independent powerapps form this list as a data source, the issue tracker list doesn't appear to be available there. Is it possible to customize an issue tracker list's form using powerapps or creating a powerapps form on the top of legacy issue tracker list in SharePoint online? or are there any other work arounds?
your suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Power Apps customized forms are only supported in modern experience currently.

You cannot customize the list forms for classic experience list forms.

**References**:

1. [SharePoint Classic experience list forms Power Apps not working](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SharePoint-Classic-experience-list-forms-powerapps-not-working/td-p/270558)
2. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

Comment: Our migrated issue tracker list is configured to be opened in modern experience hence that's not the issue but as i mentioned, option to customize list form with powerapps is not still available. To me it seems to be due to lack of support of other (legacy) list templates except custom/generic lists. Microsoft's article that you shared actually talks about it but 'Issue tracker list' template is not mentioned there. So, I wanted to be assured. Also, please suggest if you know about any work arounds to use powerapps for issue tracker list. thanks!

Comment: Yes, classic list templates are not supported to use power apps customizations.